# How to upload infopath 2013 form attachment to document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

To upload attachment via Infopath in SharePoint 2013 there is a new API, old solutions does not work, i have to make RESTful upload of infopath form attachment but i need access token , currently i can't generate token for my on-premises SharePoint server to complete the RESTful upload to the document library